# How to add a favicon to a Next.js app created using npx create-next-app

Tags: javascript, next.js, favicon, next.js14

My folder structure is the default structure provided by npx create-next-app
my-app
|__ app
|     |__ layout.js
|     |__ page.js
|
|__ public

This is a the default layout.js provided by npx create-next-app

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I tried this way but it didn't work.

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Head from 'next/head';
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Qviq - Create Share Connect",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#favicon